# Android Studio: Activity preview does not show title bar

Tags: android, android-studio, android-titlebar

i know this question has been made before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29013003/android-studio-not-showing-title-bar-in-preview), but i have tried the solution given and i don't get the preview look in the exact style like the device does.

I am using a Samsung Galaxy S3 mini on android version 4.2.2 as my device debugging, it is completely unmodified but i don't understand why, even when i change the theme, the device still looks the same (with the changes made in the activity of course)

the code of the activity is just like any new blank activity

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView android:text="@string/hello_world" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

the preview looks like this
[image]

but the device looks like this
[image]

PS: I am learning android, so i might get confused with the answer

Answer (score 30):

Had a similar problem. In my case, it was just a configuration of the design view. After I marked "Show Layout Decorations" it appeared as expected.[image: Show Layout Decorations]

Answer (score 1):

1. It looks like you have a theme defined in your **styles.xml** file that gives you the above output in your emulator.
2. Select the same theme (that is defined in your styles.xml) from the **AppTheme** option in Design view of your activity to make it show your ActionBar.

[image]

Comment: how is this defined in the file?... and when i select the same theme i'm using, it does not change

Comment: @OscarReyes I know this is very old, but have you solved the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Inorder to make your activity show title bar automatically, you need to extends your activity to AppCompatActivity not an Activity. And also make sure in your manifest.xml you didn't set your theme as

```
android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
```

but

```
android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. My problem was that in my `styles.xml` file I had this

```
<item name="windowActionBar">true</item>
<item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
```

[image]

Changed it to this and the title bar showed up again.

```
<item name="windowActionBar">true</item>
<item name="windowNoTitle">false</item>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just Go to app/scr/main/res/values/styles.xml and change your **AppTheme** style to **Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar**

```
   <!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```